# Facebook App Submission Rejection

Tags: ios, facebook, appstore-approval

In my iOS app I provide video upload functionality to user's Facebook account. I was using Facebook SDK before without any issues and few months back app was put into Sandbox mode for not updating privacy policy. Then it seems I needed to submit the Facebook app for review ! Please help me, I am very confused. I am getting the following feedback from submission :

"Your iOS app must use the native Login dialog that comes with Facebook's SDKs instead of custom web views. Ensure you have successfully tested your Facebook Login integration for Single Sign On or remove this integration as a listed platform in the developer app. See more details here"

I don't understand, my app just needs to upload videos to user's FB account and things were always working fine before they were unnecessarily made complicated.

1. I am using Social Framework part of iOS 6.0 or later for Facebook login. Is Native login different than that ?
2. Does my app still need submission and review if I use Social Framework instead of Facebook SDK ?

EDIT : Here is my code FYI.

```
     __block ACAccount * facebookAccount;
    self.accountStore = [[[ACAccountStore alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSDictionary *options = @{
                          ACFacebookAppIdKey: kAppId,
                          ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"publish_stream", ],
                          ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends
                          };
    ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [self.accountStore                                  accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

    if (granted) {
       SLRequest *request = ....
    } else {

    }
 }];
```

Comment: What code do you use for Facebook? Can you share excerpts of code to understand better what you're doing with Facebook?

Comment: Oh, ok sorry my answer was wrong, if you just use SLComposeViewController indeed you don't need to provide an AppId therefore Facebook is not involved from that perspective. I would suggest using directly Facebook SDK for everything, it handles cases where the user has a Facebook account on the device or he needs to login through the browser. As a side note, you are required to ask first for basic read permissions and at later stage you can actually ask for publish permissions (otherwise it would fail in some cases).

Comment: Yes I can use Facebook SDK but right now I updated my app using Social framework and thought the Facebook submission would go through by the time update is approved by Apple. And it sounds weird that one can not get Facebook approval without using Facebook SDK, then how and where does one use SLRequest APIs ?

Comment: Ok I have been able to move the app out of Sandbox mode through the settings, but the app is still not past Facebook review.